# Info.plist file for react native ios app using expo SDK

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, in-app-purchase, react-native-in-app-utils

I'm looking to properly format the Info.plist file in order to make in app purchase work with react-native-in-app-utils but I'm not sure how to format the data and what kind of data to insert.

This thread mentions the necessity to include the app bundle id inside the Info.plist file.

[iOS in app purchase - no products received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947805/ios-in-app-purchase-no-products-received/11707704#11707704)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

If you are using expo, it will not expose the entire `info.plist` to you.

#### Expo Workaround

You can add an object as a child of `ios` object in the `app.json` like so:

```
"infoPlist": {
  "NSCameraUsageDescription": "This app uses the camera to scan barcodes on event tickets."
},
```

Which will write to the native level but this is limited. Here is a list of all the keys you can access with while using expo

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allow Expo experiences to use your camera</string>
<key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allow Expo experiences to access your contacts</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allow Expo experiences to use your location</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allow Expo experiences to access your microphone</string>
<key>NSMotionUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allow Expo experiences to access your device's accelerometer</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>Give Expo experiences permission to save photos</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Give Expo experiences permission to access your photos</string>
```

View expos official docs [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/app-stores.html#system-permissions-dialogs-on-ios)

#### React-native Init

If you need more low level access to your project, consider using `react-native init MyProject` instead of `create-react-native-app MyProject`.

This will provide you with full access to all ios and android bundles.

#### React-native eject

Or if you already built your app via `create-react-native-app MyProject` you can run `react-native eject` to get the build of `react-native-init MyProject`.

Be cautious, there is no returning once this command is ran.

Comment: I'm not sure if this changed since you posted this answer, but expo's docs specify that you can put any arbitrary key / values in the `infoPlist` entry with no additional validation now. See the docs here: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/config/app/#infoplist

Comment: You can run `expo prebuild` to generate the native code for your project and see what the resulting `Info.plist` would be in a managed EAS build. The resulting Info.plist could be a bit different in a legacy `expo build:ios` project.

Comment: Do you know the syntax for doing this to allow `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to be true? I need to enable http calls for development but I can't get the setting detected.

Comment: This may have changed since this was originally created, but according to Expo's current info, "infoPlist" is a "Dictionary of arbitrary configuration to add to your standalone app's native Info.plist. Applied prior to all other Expo-specific configuration. No other validation is performed, so use this at your own risk of rejection from the App Store.". So should support any arbitrary Info.plist values.