# Network requests failed with React Native Expo on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

There are questions that are related but none of them answered my question so I thought let's ask it myself with some details.

I am working with a React Native build with the Expo SDK. I am using a localhost GraphQL API but it seems that iOS [prevents fetching](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network#using-other-networking-libraries) data from `http` endpoints. According to sources and other related questions, you have to [add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418998/react-native-fetch-network-request-failed) stuff to your `info.plist` file in your iOS build.

But since I am using the Expo SDK I don't have my iOS build. [According to the docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v31.0.0/guides/configuration.html#ios), you can add a `infoPList` object to your `app.json`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48157185/info-plist-file-for-react-native-ios-app-using-expo-sdk/48199702#48199702) answer suggests that as well.

So I added in my `app.js` the following but that didn't worked out:

```
"ios": {
    "supportsTablet": false,
    "infoPlist": {
        "NSAllowsArbitraryLoads": {
            "NSAllowsArbitraryLoads": true
        }
    }
}
```

I am still getting the same "Network request failed" error. Does someone know the solution to this without ejecting?

Comment: dont think you need to edit any config. You mentioned that you are using localhost. are you using real device for testing? Is your api endpoint using localhost or local ip? because localhost in the device actually doesnt point to your local dev server

Comment: I was using the expo app on my mobile, that didn't worked out. Can test it out on a simulator but don't know if that matter. How do you thikn that I can fix it? Using localhost indeed.

Comment: that's the thing. The app is running on your phone, and I guess your local dev server is running on your pc. Your phone is firing http request using localhost, but it doesnt point to your pc. You should make sure that your phone and pc are under the same local network, and change localhost to the ip of your pc.

Comment: Awesome, you're right. I found out that I fixed this issue some time ago on my personal computer but I forgot about that and wasn't able to access my personal computer yesterday. If you can explain the issue as an aswer I will choose it as the right answer :)

Comment: thanks. Added answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that localhost on your device does not point to your local dev server, which is on another machine. To fix this, you should make sure that your testing mobile device and dev server are under the same local network, and change localhost to the ip of dev server machine.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, I use fetch () to send my data from my native react application to my php server, I simulate from my IOS phone with expo but I receive the same error as you while I have configured the correct IPV4 address (fetch (http: // ipv4 address / ...)   )  and not localhost...
Also when I simulate a web view on my pc and I put fetch (http: // localhost / ..), I receive the data everything works perfectly ..