# React Native Expo iOS app - trying to modify info.plist

Tags: ios, react-native, plist, expo, info.plist

I have a React Native app set up in Expo.

**I need to modify the info.plist**, but am having problems doing so.

First, I can't find info.plist anywhere.
Based on the [Expo docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/configuration/) and this other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48157185/info-plist-file-for-react-native-ios-app-using-expo-sdk), the workaround is to add an "infoPlist" key into my app.json file. I have done so, and it looks like this:

```
"infoPlist": {
      "NSAppTransportSecurity": {
        "blah.s3.amazonaws.com": {
          "NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads": true,
          "NSRequiresCertificateTransparency": false,
          "NSIncludesSubdomains": true
        }
      }
    }
```

However when I attempt to compile the app (either by running "expo start" or "expo publish") I get the following error:

Error: Problem validating fields in app.json. See https://docs.expo.io/versions/v30.0.0/guides/configuration.html
Should NOT have additional property 'infoPlist'.

Any ideas on how I can get around this?

Answer (score 2):

The `infoPlist` property needs to be added inside `ios` section (as it has no effect on Android).

Comment: Agree; for reference, there's a sample Expo `app.json` in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64731218/is-this-the-way-to-add-string-in-infoplist-file-with-expo-bare-workflow-in-sdk-3/64747403