# is this the way to add string in infoplist file with expo bare workflow in sdk 39? #ReactNative

Tags: react-native, permissions, expo, info-plist

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Light",
    "slug": "Light",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
    "ios": {
      "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.ShivBaapYaadHai.Light",
      "buildNumber": "1.5.0",
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSCameraUsageDescription": "Enable Camera Acess so that you can record  Videos",
        "NSMicrophoneUsageDescription": "Enable Microphone Access so that you can start recording audio ",
        "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription": "Enable Camera Roll Access so that you can select Other Videos from Camera Roll"
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
      "package": "com.ShivBabaYaadHai.Light",
      "versionCode": 1
    },
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

this is my app.json file so is this the way to add infoplist file in expo bare workflow ya some other way because I need to add some string when system ask permissions from user.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you've got it. That is the same shape as my app.json that sets `expo.ios.infoPlist` and requests similar permissions.

Comment: you mean you added this and you got the same errors back when submitting it to Apple? in that case, i'm not really sure. my strings were more specific as to the exact use case for wanting each specific permission (eg "I want to use the camera to support this feature in the app")

Comment: no no i didn’t get any error. I mean to say that it didn’t change any message in the alert box. The string i’ve added in my infoplist file doesn’t displayed on a alert box. This string is not showing up in alert box and  it didn’t gave  any error also. It’s just not working in this way.