# How to enable HTTP calls on React Native Expo

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, expo, info-plist

I have a React Native project built using Expo. To test my API locally I need to be able to make calls to it via HTTP. There are lots of resources on how to do this, but none of them describe how to do it for Expo.

Basically the solution without Expo is to edit `Info.plist` and insert this into it ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http)):

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Since you can't edit `Info.plist` directly when using Expo, you can access it in `app.config.js` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48157185/info-plist-file-for-react-native-ios-app-using-expo-sdk). However, the *only* example I can find on how to do this comes from the above link, and does not show how to do it with dictionaries. The expo docs themselves don't provide an example either (see [here](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/app/#infoplist)), so despite knowing the solution, I do not have any idea on how to implement it syntactically.

Within `app.config.js`, I've tried

```
export default {
  ...
  ios: {
    infoPlist: {
      "NSAppTransportSecurity": [
        {
          "xml": "<dict><key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true /></dict>"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and have also tried

```
export default {
  ...
  ios: {
    infoPlist: {
        "NSAppTransportSecurity": {
            "NSAllowsArbitraryLoads": true
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Saving these and re-running `expo start`, I still get the same `Network Request Failed` error. Can anyone help me format this?

Comment: there are other reasons you could have that error - what device are you testing on? can you show the network call?

Comment: Testing on an iPhone 13, the identical network call works perfectly from Postman or a regular react app on web. It's to an internal API and looks like `http://(localhost)/get_prices`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An external device won't share your machine's network, so you can't use localhost addresses. You can only use localhost for the iOS simulator. For all other testing, get your computer's local IP address and use that instead. Ex: `fetch('http://192.168.1.4:8080/route')`