# Prompting user to select an app from the list of related apps in React-Native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am using react-native and I have a requirement where I have a button called **Get Directions**, which on being clicked should show a list of related apps (Apple Maps, Google Maps, Waze, etc.) installed on the user's device, and allow the user to select one of the options to navigate to the selected app.

I am facing a problem where I am not able to find the related apps installed on the user's device. This should work on both Android and iOS. I have already tried using different libraries like **react-native-check-app-install** and **react-native-installed-application**. Is there an inbuilt native API for this or if anyone else has successfully implemented this?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: On iOS you need to identify if the relevant app has a url scheme, add that url scheme to your info.plist and the use `canOpenUrl` to see if the app is installed.

Comment: @Paulw11 yes, google maps has a URL scheme **comgooglemaps://** and apple maps has a URL scheme **maps://**. But how can we do it in Expo as there is no info.plist file

Comment: There must be an info.plist file somewhere.  It is a requirement for every iOS app

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48199702/3418066

Comment: @Paulw11 I am quite new to react-native. One thing I am not able to figure out is in app.json file, I have added **infoPlist** object under ios, added the key called **NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription**, but what should be the value based on the above URL schemes.

Comment: You need to add [`LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009250-SW14) not a location use description (although if your app is using location services then you will need a use description as well)

Comment: @Paulw11 I have added  this with the value as an array of string containing **comgooglemaps** but it is still not working as expected.